# Java 8 Streams Filter Intention of Lazy Evaluation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is either option 1 or option 2 below correct (e.g. one preferred over the other) or are they equivalent?

**Option 1**

```
collectionOfThings.
    stream().
    filter(thing -> thing.condition1() && thing.condition2())
```

or

**Option 2**

```
collectionOfThings
    .stream()
    .filter(thing -> thing.condition1())
    .filter(thing -> thing.condition2())
```

Comment: The answer for the previous question is incorrect. I'm not a benchmarking expert, but my own tests show that Option1 can perform significantly better.  I'll post my test code to the other question, and I would appreciate anyone's review of my findings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To compile, the second one should be

```
collectionOfThings.
    stream().
    filter(thing -> thing.condition1()).
    filter(thing -> thing.condition2())
```

They're both equivalent. Sometimes one is more readable than the other.

An alternative way of writing the second one would be to use a method reference:

```
collectionOfThings
    .stream()
    .filter(Thing::condition1)
    .filter(Thing::condition2)
```

Also note that the convention is to place the dot at the beginning of the line rather than the end, as you would write a bulleted list.

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted the example to fix the errors.